# Explanation of a function line by line for learning purposes!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

As the title says, I need someone to give me an explanation of this function below, line by line, for learning purposes.

Thank you in advance!!!

```
function getAllShapeLayersData() {
    var lyrs = [];
    try {
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        var layers = 0
    }
    catch (e) {
        var layers = 1;
    };
    while (true) {
        ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try {
            var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
        }
        catch (err) {
            break;
        }

        var lyr = {};
        lyr.type = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
        lyr.name = desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));
        lyr.id = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerID"));

        if (lyr.type == 4) { // shape layer
            var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0);

            if (adj.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("color"))) {
                var curColor = new SolidColor();
                curColor.rgb.red = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("red"));
                curColor.rgb.green = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("grain"));
                curColor.rgb.blue = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("blue"));
                lyr.color = curColor;
                lyrs.push(lyr);
            }
        }
        layers++;
    }
    return lyrs
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// make new function named getAllShapeLayersData
function getAllShapeLayersData() {

    // make empty list lyrs (for returning later)
    var lyrs = [];

    //if the thing in try fails go to catch
    try {
        // get the background layer
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        var layers = 0
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Ok so there was no background layer
        var layers = 1;
        // note: this is probably copied code one
        // could skip this the shape layer is unlikely 
        // to be a background layer cos it can not be. 
        // But ok defensive coding is fine
    };
    // ok lets loop untill we reach a future condition
    while (true) {

        // lets prepare a object cor accepting the hooks for 
        // the nonscripting  raw c API, you can find these functions 
        // with the script listener plugin, they are a bit 
        // clunky cos its c++ not really javascript.
        ref = new ActionReference();
        // Fetch layer with index layers
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try {
            // get the raw api object
            var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
        }
        catch (err) {
            // well that didn't work lets quit the loop
            break;
        }

        // Lets make a object lyr for easier use that has
        var lyr = {};
        // members type kind and raw c API ID
        lyr.type = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
        lyr.name = desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));
        lyr.id = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerID"));

        if (lyr.type == 4) { // shape layer

            // get the adjustment layer (fill in most cases)
            var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0);

            // well ok so we dont actually know what adjustment layer we have.
            // But does it have a color value we can change? (i.e. a fill)
            if (adj.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("color"))) {
                // buld a color
                var curColor = new SolidColor();
                // fetch red, green and blue color
                curColor.rgb.red = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("red"));
                curColor.rgb.green = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("grain"));
                curColor.rgb.blue = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("blue"));
                // add it to the object we created with type, name, id
                lyr.color = curColor;
                // add it to the return list
                lyrs.push(lyr);
            }
        } // exit both ifs
        // increment layers by one 
        layers++;
    } // and loop
    // return a list of objects that have name, id , type and color of layer.
    return lyrs
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!!! This `if (lyr.type == 4)` how do we know that is a shape layer? Is there any list so to know what is what? Or, is there any way to do something like this `if (lyr.type == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL)`?

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek No, different API.

Comment: And how do I know what every number is? Is there a list or something?

Comment: Well presumably the original script maker iterated trough every object they have and printed the type value and looked at the name and type.

Comment: And one last thing (except if I have to create a new question for this)... It "says" `if (lyr.type == 4) {`. What if I want to make an if condition by it's color and not it's type?

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek then you add a if inside the if after the color is fetched.

Comment: @joojaa commented code are always welcomed for someone like me who still learning  :D loved explaination +1 for that